# Using NSArray<MyProtocol> and NSDictionaty<MyProtocol>

Tags: objective-c

I faced with two declaration `NSArray<MyProtocol>` and `NSDictionary<MyProtocol>`. I didn't find correct explanation of it and how work correct with it.

Comment: What's your question? You're familiar with protocols? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html (It's similar to Java's interface)

Comment: Yes. I think that NSArray<MyProtocol> and NSDictionary<MyProtocol> are generics. But I'm not sure.

Comment: It looks like to be Generics.
NSArray<MyProtocol> <= can be an array of item conforming to MyProtocol (if MyProtocol is actually a protocol)

NSDictionary<MyProtocol> <= is a bit wrong because NSDict are KeyValue Pair so it should be NSDictionary<MyProtocol,MyProtocol>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this may be related to a clever macro that did the rounds recently ([possibly this one](https://github.com/tomersh/Objective-C-Generics), there are a lot of similar projects on GitHub).

The values stored by `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` are of type `id`. This basically means that the type of the objects being stored is untyped. The problem with this is a that you loose type safety. The macro in question attempted to address this problem by creating a protocol that is applied to the array/dictionary so that the returned objects have a more specific type than `id`.

In Xcode you can find where `<MyProtocol>` is being declared by cmd+clicking on it `<MyProtocol>`.

Personally I would avoid using such macros. They are solving a problem, but the solution is not in keeping with the Objective-C ethos. I would solve this problem by one or more of the following:

- ensuring the collection has a descriptive instance/variable name
- creating another class that wraps the collection.